# Array Return always the same value

Tags: php

I don't find the solution how to resolve this point

```
var_dump($orders_status_support_array[$value['orders_status_support_id']]);
```

return always the same value

thank you.

```
                $QordersHistory = $this->app->db->prepare('select orders_status_support_id,
                                                                  orders_status_history_id
                                                            from :table_orders_status_history
                                                            where orders_id = :orders_id
                                                            order by date_added desc
                                                           ');
                $QordersHistory->bindInt(':orders_id',$oID);
                $QordersHistory->execute();

$order_array = $QordersHistory->fetchAll();

foreach ($order_array as $value)
{
    $QordersStatusSupport = $this->app->db->prepare('select orders_status_support_id,
                                                                 orders_status_support_name
                                                           from :table_orders_status_support
                                                           where language_id = :language_id
                                                            and orders_status_support_id = :orders_status_support_id
                                                          ');    
    $QordersStatusSupport->bindInt(':language_id', $CLICSHOPPING_Language->getId());
    $QordersStatusSupport->bindInt(':orders_status_support_id', $value['orders_status_support_id']);
    $QordersStatusSupport->execute();

    $orders_status_support_array[$value['orders_status_support_id']] = $QordersStatusSupport->value('orders_status_support_name');
}
```

**result of :** `var_dump(orders_status_support_array)`

```
array(3) { [2]=> string(7) "Pending" [4]=> string(8) "Resolved" [3]=> string(7) "Process" } array(3) { [2]=> string(7) "Pending" [4]=> string(8) "Resolved" [3]=> string(7) "Process" } array(3) { [2]=> string(7) "Pending" [4]=> string(8) "Resolved" [3]=> string(7) "Process"
```

**result of:** `var_dump($orders_status_support_array[$value['orders_status_support_id']]);`

```
string(7) "Process" string(7) "Process" string(7) "Process"
```

**var_dump($value)**

```
array(2) { ["orders_status_support_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["orders_status_history_id"]=> string(2) "15" } array(2) { ["orders_status_support_id"]=> string(1) "4" ["orders_status_history_id"]=> string(2) "14" } array(2) { ["orders_status_support_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["orders_status_history_id"]=> string(2) "13" } string(7) "Process" array(2) { ["orders_status_support_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["orders_status_history_id"]=> string(2) "15" } array(2) { ["orders_status_support_id"]=> string(1) "4" ["orders_status_history_id"]=> string(2) "14" } array(2) { ["orders_status_support_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["orders_status_history_id"]=> string(2) "13" } string(7) "Process" array(2) { ["orders_status_support_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["orders_status_history_id"]=> string(2) "15" } array(2) { ["orders_status_support_id"]=> string(1) "4" ["orders_status_history_id"]=> string(2) "14" } array(2) { ["orders_status_support_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["orders_status_history_id"]=> string(2) "13" } string(7) "Process"
```

Comment: Can you `var_dump()` `$value`?

Comment: @Dammeul : Tk, result above

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue might be a key issue...

Basically, you're looking for:

`$orders_status_support_array[2]`

`2` is the `index` as `orders_status_support_id` in `$value` is 2.

The 3rd element, or index `2` `[0,1,2]` in the `$orders_status_support_array` is `"Process"` so it looks like it may not be respecting your index numbers, and rather treated them sequentially.

Are you able to test this theory by including all status' in `$orders_status_support_array` rather than just the 3 you are including, and order them correctly?

**For example:**

```
0 => "Other Status 1"
1 => "Other Status 2"
2 => "Pending"
3 => "Process"
4 => "Resolved"
```

Currently, the first 2 elements seem to be missing, and elements `4` and `3` are the wrong way around.

Tidy the array, include the other status' have them in a normal key order, ie, `0, 1, 2, 3, 4` etc. and you should find it easier to get this working.

Does that make sense?

Comment: ok, thank you for all this explanations, but no idea to write the code to make that. Could give me a way ?